# Filter array of objects where children must match all conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to parse through an array of objects with embedded arrays of objects which I know I can do with .filter(). However I need to check if the embedded array has at least one of multiple types of objects. See example below:

I have an array of Garage objects that have a "cars" field which is an array of cars. Each car is an object with an array of qualities. I need to see which garages has at least one "fast" car AND at least one "tiny" car. It is ok if both qualities fall under the same car. What is the quickest/most efficient way to accomplish this in javascript?

```
garageArray = [
 {
  id: 10,
  cars: [
   {id: 1, qualities: ["fast", "small"]},
   {id: 2, qualities: ["offRoad", "large"]},
   {id: 3, qualities: ["fast", "loud"]}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 20,
  cars: [
   {id: 4, qualities: ["loud"]},
   {id: 5, qualities: ["fast", "tiny"]}
  ]
 },
 {
  id: 30,
  cars: [
   {id: 6, qualities: ["slow", "small"]},
   {id: 7, qualities: ["offRoad", "tiny"]},
   {id: 8, qualities: ["fast", "loud"]}
  ]
 }
]
```

The result should be Garages with ids of 20 and 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
garageArray.filter(garage =>
    garage.cars.some(car => car.qualities.includes("fast")) &&
    garage.cars.some(car => car.qualities.includes("tiny"))
);
```

But a more general solution to match *n* properties is as follows:

```js
const garageArray = [
    {
        id: 10,
        cars: [
            { id: 1, qualities: ["fast", "small"] },
            { id: 2, qualities: ["offRoad", "large"] },
            { id: 3, qualities: ["fast", "loud"] }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 20,
        cars: [
            { id: 4, qualities: ["loud"] },
            { id: 5, qualities: ["fast", "tiny"] }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 30,
        cars: [
            { id: 6, qualities: ["slow", "small"] },
            { id: 7, qualities: ["offRoad", "tiny"] },
            { id: 8, qualities: ["fast", "loud"] }
        ]
    }
];

var featuresTofind = ["loud", "fast", "tiny"];

var result = garageArray.filter(function (garage) {
    var featuresFound = featuresTofind.filter(function (feature) {
        return garage.cars.some(function (car) {
            return car.qualities.includes(feature);
        });
    });
    return featuresFound.length === featuresTofind.length;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I would use `.includes("fast")` instead of `.indexOf("fast") >=0`

Comment: I am getting too old for this.

Answer (score 2):

the drawback is looping cars twice :-) hope it is ok.

```
garageArray.filter(garage => {
    return garage.cars.some(car => {
        return car.qualities.includes("fast")
    }) && garage.cars.some(car => {
        return car.qualities.includes("tiny")
    });
})
```